# Android - How to display online value chart bar using MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, json, charts

There's a way how to set a value chart bar obtained from `JSON` website like this below??

`[
  {
    "nilai": "1",
    "jumlah": "18"
  },
  {
    "nilai": "2",
    "jumlah": "2"
  },
  {
    "nilai": "3",
    "jumlah": "7"
  },
  {
    "nilai": "4",
    "jumlah": "6"
  },
  {
    "nilai": "5",
    "jumlah": "3"
  }
]`

that's `nilai` is constant and the `jumlah` may changed the value,

I've reference from [here](http://www.android-examples.com/create-bar-chart-graph-using-mpandroidchart-library/) but it's offline data.

I've tried to find any tutorial on internet, but the clue is scrimpy,

I'm using this code to try but i'm stuck at how to change `AddValuesToBARENTRY()` to my `jumlah` and `AddValuesToBarEntryLabels()` to my `nilai` from [here](http://www.android-examples.com/create-bar-chart-graph-using-mpandroidchart-library/)

```
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

            String jumlah = c.getString("jumlah");
            String nilai = c.getString("nilai");
            HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

            contact.put("id", nilai);
            contact.put("name", jumlah);
            contactList.add(contact);
```

Comment: any idea please how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Please give me some idea